# What extra does the Master Volume Key provide in BitLocker?

Tags: security, keyboard, encryption, truecrypt

From this [FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-key-management-faq), I understand that BitLocker uses the following keys to encrypt the hard-drive:

- Full Volume Encryption Key (FVEK) (used to encrypt raw data; encrypted by the volume master key and stored on-disk)
- Volume Master Key (VMK) (encrypted by a key protector and stored on-disk)
- Key Protector (KP) (TPM or numerical password)

I don't understand what security value the VMK provides. Why not just encrypt the FVEK directly using KPs?

In any case, if a KP leaks, the FVEK can be obtained anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in the article
[BitLocker Drive Encryption Technical Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732774%28v=ws.10%29).

The section
[BitLocker Architecture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732774(v=ws.10)#bitlocker-architecture)
contains a nice diagram and this text:

> Figure 1 shows how the BitLocker-protected volume is encrypted with a full volume encryption key, which in turn is encrypted with a volume master key. Securing the volume master key is an indirect way of protecting data on the volume: the addition of the volume master key allows the system to be re-keyed easily when keys upstream in the trust chain are lost or compromised. This ability to re-key the system saves the expense of decrypting and encrypting the entire volume again.

The idea is that the authentication mechanisms are all capable of decrypting the Volume Master Key (VMK), which then in turn can unlock the Full Volume Encryption Key (FVEK).
This means that if any individual authentication part is compromised, the VMK can be changed *without* having the re-encrypt all of the data on the disk, by changing the VMK and re-encrypting the FVEK with it.

BitLocker itself does not provide any functionality to change the FVEK, as it would require decrypting and re-encrypting the entire volume, but
changing the VMK is possible.

Comment: Doesn't the idea of changing the VMK only make sense in the case that an attacker gains access to the VMK by means of a KP (authentication mechanism; although a TPM doesn't provide any authentication), but then cannot get SYSTEM to dump the FVEK? Otherwise, it won't help to chance the VMK?

Comment: Also, are the FVEK used to it encrypt multiple volumes, if the computer has multiple hard drives?

Comment: BitLocker can encrypt multiple drives ([helpful link](https://superuser.com/questions/964825/easiest-way-to-encrypt-multiple-hard-drives). Changing the VMK is a quick remedy if other keys were compromised.

Comment: Yes, but in a complete system compromise, changing the VMK would provide no value would it? It only makes sense for a unprivileged or partial system compromise, right?

Comment: In this case a full re-encryption is required. This is safer, but much much slower.

Comment: Thank you, done 